# Firebase Auth error attempting sign-in offline continues even after coming back online

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, offline, google-signin

**Description**

Calling either `signInWithRedirect()` or `signInWithPopup()` while offline will throw the expected error O

> {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}.

However, returning online and calling `signInWithRedirect()` or `signInWithPopup()` again will throw the same error. Any attempt to call these functions afterwards results in the same error unless the browser is refreshed.

**Expected outcome**

Auth sign-in functions normally after coming back online

**Actual outcome**

Auth sing-in throws an error and continues to do so on any following attempts

**Steps to reproduce**

- Go offline Call either `signInWithRedirect()` or `signInWithPopup()` (error should be logged here: O {code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."})
- Go online
- Call either `signInWithRedirect()` or `signInWithPopup()` (same error occurs on every sign-in attempt

Can anybody provide a solution to this?

Comment: I am only able to reproduce this for signInWithRedirect. If you call signInWithPopup once when network is offline and then call it again when online it works. Can you confirm?

Comment: Will confirm. But yeah signInWithRedirect doesnt work for sure.

Answer (score 2):

*firebaser here*

We've been able to confirm this behavior with `signInWithRedirect()`. This is indeed a bug. We'll fix it in an upcoming version.

**Update**: This should be fixed in [version 4.1.3](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.1.3).

Comment: Hi Frank, can you please provide me a bug/issue ID so that we can track it. Thanks

Comment: This should be fixed in 4.1.3: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.1.3

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to take place on Firebase JavaScript SDK 9.5.0 (and potentially with earlier recent releases).

The steps to reproduce are the same as described above. A few additional observations:

- If the first call is made to signInWithRedirect, and it fails due to network connection, subsequent calls both to signInWithRedirect and signInWithPopup result in 'auth/network-request-failed' error even after the network connection is restored.
- However, if the first call is made to signInWithPopup, and it fails due to network connection, subsequent calls both to signInWithRedirect and signInWithPopup will succeed after the network connection is restored.